# How to use a For loop to get user input in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, user-input

My entire code is posted below. My issue can be seen in this output:

```
Enter the character representation of your first configuration: p
How many symbols are under this configuration? 3
Enter the first symbol: Enter the first symbol: 1
Enter the first symbol: None
[, 1, None]
```

As you can see, the first iteration of the for loop is executed without getting user input. It appears as if it has been skipped.

My question is this: **How do I create a For loop that will ask for user input for each iteration of the loop?** Not skip an iteration as my code is doing now. I've looked all over the internet for the answer, but I can't find anything specifically.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create instance of class
        Tape instructions = new Tape();


        // Assign scanner to keyboard variable
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        // Get user input for mConfig and convert to char
        System.out.print("Enter the character representation of your first configuration: ");
        String userMConfig = keyboard.nextLine();
        char c = userMConfig.charAt(0);


        // Get number of symbols/operations/f-configurations
        System.out.print("How many symbols are under this configuration? ");
        int numOfSymbols = keyboard.nextInt();


        // Define array of symbols
        ArrayList<String> userSymbols = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i<= numOfSymbols; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the first symbol: ");
            String userInputSymbol = keyboard.nextLine();
            userSymbols.add(userInputSymbol);

        }



        // Assign values to object methods
        instructions.mConfig(c);
        instructions.symbols(userSymbols);



        // Testing code
        System.out.println(instructions.getSymbols());





    }
}
```

Here is just my For loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i<= numOfSymbols; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the first symbol: ");
                String userInputSymbol = keyboard.nextLine();
                userSymbols.add(userInputSymbol);

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this

```
int numOfSymbols = keyboard.nextInt();
```

the scanner takes the integer portion from your input line, but leaves `'\n'` in the buffer. That is why when you call

```
String userInputSymbol = keyboard.nextLine();
```

from the first iteration of your loop, that `'\n'` gets returned immediately, producing an empty line.

To fix this problem, add `keyboard.nextLine();` right after reading `numOfSymbols`:

```
int numOfSymbols = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine(); // Throw away the '\n' from the line that contained int
```

Alternatively, you could use `keyboard.nextLine()` followed by parsing an `int` manually for reading the integer.

In general, you should be careful mixing `nextLine` with other calls to `Scanner`'s methods, precisely because of the issue of trailing `'\n'` characters.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `nextInt()` reads an int, and leaves the newline character in the stream. Then, call to `nextLine()` reads this character and return empty string. To avoid that use the following:

```java
int numOfSymbols = keyboard.nextInt();

keyboard.nextLine(); // this will swallow the "\n"

// Now your for loop should work fine
for (int i = 0; i < numOfSymbols; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the first symbol: ");
    String userInputSymbol = keyboard.nextLine();
    userSymbols.add(userInputSymbol);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens becasue `nextInt()` doesn't consume the end-of-line character.

**What can you do?** You can consume it manually after the `nextInt()` call:

```
int numOfSymbols = keyboard.nextInt();
...
keyboard.nextLine(); // Consume the end-of-line character

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfSymbols; i++) {
    ...
}
```

You can refer to [this post](https://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/) if you want more information.